# jQuery: height() for a border-box

Tags: jquery, html, css

Its stated in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

> **Note that .height() will always return the content height, regardless
>   of the value of the CSS box-sizing property.** As of jQuery 1.8, this
>   may require retrieving the CSS height plus box-sizing property and
>   then subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when
>   the element has box-sizing: border-box. To avoid this penalty, use
>   .css( "height" ) rather than .height().

I tried the following example

```
<div id='wrapper' class='boxA'>
  <div class='boxB'>
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

with the CSS

```
.boxA{
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 50px;
}

.boxB{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

According to the jQUery API I was sure that

```
$('#wrapper').height($('#wrapper').height());
```

would set the height of boxA to 50px (since the content-height is 50px) but I found that the height was set to 90px.
However if I use

```
$('#wrapper').css('height', $('#wrapper').height()+"px");
```

the height of boxA gets 50px and therefore shrinks. Why is the first method not producing 50px height as well?

Furthermore, the command

```
$('#wrapper').height($('#wrapper').css('height'));
```

will set the height of boxA to 130px but `$('#wrapper').css('height')` returns 90. What happened here?

You may find these examples in this [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p390tspb/).

Comment: _"...As of jQuery 1.8, this may require retrieving the CSS height plus box-sizing property and then **subtracting** any potential `border` and `padding` on each element when the element has box-sizing: border-box."_

Comment: @Vucko I added the full comment now. It still does not explain to me the weird behavior described in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery API says

> Note that .height() will always return the content height, regardless
>   of the value of the CSS box-sizing property.

This implies that `$('#wrapper').height()` is 50px (since content-height of boxA is 50px) and `$('#wrapper').css('height')` is 90px (because you have a top-padding of 20px and a bottom-padding of 20px) and 
for a `border-box` the height is given by content-height + padding + border. Furthermore the API states that

> Note that .height(value) sets the content height of the box regardless
>   of the value of the CSS box-sizing property.

Thus, if one uses

```
$('#wrapper').height($('#wrapper').height());
```

then the content-height will be set to 50px, but since you have a `border-box` this implies that `height=90px` ,because the height is content-height+padding+border (adding twice padding of 20px).

This also applies to your second example

```
$('#wrapper').height($('#wrapper').css('height'));
```

in order to change the content-height to 90px, the total height of your `border-box` must be 90px+20px+20px=130px.

Therefore, everything is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `.height()` is always measured by `content-box`, but when applying new value it respects `box-sizing`, so it's adding measured `content-box` value to rest of settings as box have `border-box` set up.

If you change `box-sizing` to `content-box` at demo, it will behave exactly like that (will in all cases set `50px` to each box, and with `content-box` value all boxes will have 90px).

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery documentation:

> **.outerHeight()**
>
> Get the current computed outer height (including padding, border, and optionally margin) for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the outer height of every matched element.

So in my case it was as simple as:

```javascript
$(element).outerHeight();
```

And in author's

```javascript
$('#wrapper').outerHeight();
```